# What kind of meats are safe to feed to a 13-month old?

Tags: toddler, feeding, nutrition

My 13-month old boy is transitioning from jars of Gerber Baby Food to table food.  He does very well on toast and cheerios and other similar things, but he doesn't much like eggs, and we want to make sure he's getting enough protein and fat in his diet.

Fully raw meat is a bit difficult to keep circulated in the house on a regular basis, deli meat has the listeria risk and doesn't last for much longer, and I'm worried that canned meat will have too much sodium in it for his diet.

What's the safest, most reliable way to ensure my son is getting a regular intake of protein and fat in his diet?

Comment: How do you get meat in *your* diet?  What is your normal meal?

Comment: @Joe We take turns preparing meals throughout the week, though some days neither of us are up for it and we either order out or bring food home from the store - but even on days like that, we still need to feed our son something healthy.

Comment: Understood, but what is it that you are preparing or ordering?  Your question mostly eliminated the standard answers, so - what do you actually eat?

Comment: To put it a different way - one answer I might consider is "feed them what you are eating".  Is that a possibility? Do you eat a balanced nutritious meal?  What foods are you eating?

Comment: @Joe I guess my answer to that is, under normal circumstances we try to feed him the same things we're eating, but we try to prepare it with less sodium.  It's okay if we have a few meals that aren't perfect, but we don't want to feed our son too much sodium-loaded food. When he's a bit older, takeout food and quick meals occasionally might be okay. But he's only one year old right now and he needs good nutrition.

Comment: You're still not answering my question.  What foods do you eat?  What was your dinner yesterday? Day before that?  Breakfast?  How are we supposed to talk about how you can feed your infant appropriately if we don't know what *you* eat?

Comment: @Joe - The OP has expressed what he thinks is an answer, and I see it. Presume that the OP wants to feed the child differently than they feed themselves. It's been asked and answered.

Comment: Do you bake? Do you use your freezer? We're happy to help, but how much do you know about nutrition? We can help you sneak in healthy foods if you *know* what healthy foods are. :)

Comment: We do bake, and we do make things like baby-safe stir fry vegetables, soups that we can easily puree for him, spaghetti that we can cut up for him, and other stuff that's generally okay for him to eat - I'm more concerned with nights where we *don't* feel like cooking at all, and either order out some pizza/sushi/chinese, but still need to make something for our son.

Comment: I happily feed my son pizza/sushi/Chinese occasionally, as the rest of his diet has very little salt in it!

Comment: @RDavies If that is your answer, it would honestly be appreciated.  A lot of the reason I'm asking this right now is anxiety over the idea of feeding my son an inappropriate diet because of our takeout habits, so if the answer is "it's actually fine to do that sometimes", it would be a reassuring thing to hear.

Comment: Why not legumes for protein? Soak over night and boil for 10-20 minutes in a pressure cooker.

Comment: @iulia A 24-hour prep time is absolutely not what I'm looking for in this circumstance - I'm more looking for something I can make quickly without having to prepare ahead of time for it.

Comment: @Zibbobz There is also the option of canned beans (preferably with no/low added salt). Legumes are a great source of protein and it would add variety in your child's diet (and your own, of course). https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/are-canned-beans-healthy#benefits

Answer (score 6):

Several possible solutions:

1. Just feed them exactly what you are having, cut up appropriately. Don't worry if you think the food might be too flavoursome or spicy, let them have a go anyway. You do not need to feed your child bland food. Also kids need fat to grow, more calories than you'd think and some salt is required in moderation. The NHS in the UK has some great resources on cutting up the food so its easier for kids to get to grips with on the  [start4life](https://www.nhs.uk/start4life/weaning/safe-weaning/preparing-food-safely/#anchor-tabs) site, along with recipe ideas and healthy eating advice. Note in British English "weaning" refers to starting a baby on solid foods, as well as the process of stopping milk feeds.
2. If for some reason you can't feed them exactly what you have. Can you batch cook something at the weekend/when you do cooking and freeze small child portions you can defrost and reheat in the week. The BBC good food website has a whole load of ["toddler" friendly recipies](https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/search?q=toddler)
3. Deli meats are fine if you cook them, here is something from the Australian food standards agency [Listeria and food - advice for people at risk](https://www.foodstandards.gov.au/publications/pages/listeriabrochuretext.aspx)
4. Meat and eggs are not the only protein sources here is some infomation from BBC good food [Best sources of protein](https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/howto/guide/best-sources-protein) my toddler LOVES greek style yoghurt. Tofu is also nice and soft and easy to eat. Peanut butter on toast is another hit, though spread it thinly and use smooth peanut butter.

Comment: Thank you - we *usually* try to feed some of what we have to our son, but on some nights we order stuff that isn't appropriate for his age group, and I was hoping to hear some ideas for what we could prepare for him without much fuss.  These suggestions definitely fit the bill.

Comment: @Zibbobz I can't think of a single grown up food that is actually unsafe for a kid (alcoholic drinks of course are a no go). If you just think he won't like it because it is grown up flavouring, just let him try anyway and make clear he has a choice. You will be surprised what kind of foods your son will gladly eat.